# Intermediate recursive function value in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

Suppose we want to implement the following recursive function in Scheme:

> f(n) = f(n-1) + 1/f(n-1) [n>0]
>   f(n) = 1 [n=0]

A simple way to this is by something like this:

`(define (f n) (if (zero? n) 1 (+ (f (- n 1)) (/ 1 (f (- n 1))))))`

But, as *(f (- n 1))* subexpression is repeated, this code is not that much elegant. Is there any way to improve this code by binding a name to this intermediate value?

Note that a *let* construct can't be used here, as theoretically this causes the function to recurse forever. Practically it causes an Scheme error.

**UPDATE**:

Here is my code with let:

```
(define (afunc s n)
    (if (> n 0)
        (* .5
            (let ((next (afunc s (- n 1)))
                (+ next (/ s next))))
                s)))
```

It breaks with an **Ill-formed special form: (let (... ...))** error.

Comment: You have a parenthesis problem; the `(+ next ...` is inside the `let`'s binding list, and `s` is not the `if`'s "else".

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo, you are right, I forgot the fact Scheme's _if_ always needs three arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, let does not impose a problem, the following works as expected.

```
(define (f n)
  (if (zero? n)
      1
      (let ((next (f (- n 1))))
        (+ next (/ 1 next)))))
```

Comment: Thanks @christoph. Your code worked for me. Please see the updated question.